# Importing a class imports the classes it has imported automatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If I have three classes:

ClassA
ClassB
ClassC

They all have import statements to import each other i.e. ClassC imports ClassB and ClassB imports ClassA only.

Given this design, does ClassC have access to ClassA automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: in any case import/include doesn't make one class to have access to another class, it just makes class A to know about class B.

Second: visibility is determined by where you imported headers.
If you did import ClassA header in the ClassB header and then imported ClassB header in ClassC header than yes, ClassC knows about ClassA. But if imported it in an implementation file then the answer is no.

Edit: should notice that it's better to make class forward declarations in header and then include appropriate one in an implementation file.

Comment: That is fantastic.  I am now going to create a Base class which imports all the usual stuff then I don't need to do it over and over.  Then all my classes can import it.

Comment: Little tip: if you want some class to be visible to all other ones, you can include it in your precompiled header (by default it is in Other Sources group of your project with name <Your_project_name>_Prefix.pch)

Comment: Yah I tried that before and it didn't work.  Suppose I should sort that out somehow.